# BLE hardware in smartphone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, smartphone

I have Micromax canvas Nitro smartphone ,It works on android kitkat 4.4.Based on the specs it supports  Bluetooth 4.0.(no info whether LE is supported)

I was trying to check whether it supports Bluetooth Low Energy by following methods :

1)I downloaded some BLE apps from google playstore & tried opening it. It showed BLE not supported.Most of the apps showed the same info.Before concluding i tried the next method.

2)I opened the settings in the phone and performed a normal scan in Bluetooth menu.I have a BLE transmitter device which advertises often.

To my surprise My phone scanned that ble device and i paired it ! but i couldnt use any android ble apps to scan and see its characteristics !

So does it mean that my phone have BLE hardware which scans BLE devices but no appropiate BLE stack ?.

But why while using most of the BLE apps it is showing BLE not supported  ?

Comment: Why don't you just check the capabilities of your Smartphone on their website ?. Check whether it supports Bluetooth 4.0 or Bluetooth 4.1.

Comment: It is Bluetooth 4.0 , even nexus 7 is bluetooth 4.0 but the apps works in it  ,not in canvas nitro !? strange !

Comment: Your device is almost certainly not BLE capable, and that transmitter might be dual mode. Can't you just look on the box of your smartphone whether it is BT/BLE or both?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, but I may have an answer for you.  Many BLE modules also have built-in Classic Bluetooth functionality as well.  In addition, many manufacturers of these 2-in-1 devices create BLE profiles to very-nearly mirror the same functionality as the Classic Bluetooth.

What does this mean for the phone you were working with? It probably was not BLE compatible.  You were picking up the Classic Bluetooth signal being broadcasted at the same time and misperceiving it as a BLE signal.

...Or may be I am completely wrong.  I have learned that nothing is for certain in BLE development on both Android and iOS.

Edit:  Another important tidbit of info is that just because your phone is running on 4.3+ does not necessarily mean that it will have BLE functionality

Comment: Why the downvote? All the information I have provided can only be helpful

Comment: Indeed, no reason for a downvote. I upvoted, since it's a solid answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Discovery phase of Classic Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy (Smart) is almost identical.

Many classic chips can actually enumerate the BLE devices, even down to discovering services, but not actually communicate with them. A good stack will mask out what they cant communicate with, but looks like you have found some sloppy code.